# Clojure current system date

Tags: date, clojure, clj-time

How do I convert the result I got from clj-time into a real date.

```
require [clj-time.core :as t]

(t/today)    
;; [#<LocalDate 2015-08-25> 15]
```

I need the date like this:

```
;; 2015-08-25
```

Comment: @Andre: it's not called, *"unparsing"*, anymore? :)

Comment: Sure, I already did this: 
    (f/unparse (f/formatter "yyyy-MM-dd") (t/today))

but got an error that says:
    org.joda.time.LocalDate cannot be cast to org.joda.time.ReadableInstant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

joda time, therefore clj-time somehow distinguish between "regular" date-time and local-date-time; since `(t/today)` is a `org.joda.time.LocalDate` try `unparse-local`:

```
user=> (f/unparse-local (f/formatter "Y-MM-dd") (t/today))
"2015-08-25"
```